# Eigenvalue equation - angular bracket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenfunctions

How do you read this formula?

$$\left\langle \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( \alpha\beta - \beta\alpha) \bigg\rvert \hat{S^2} \bigg\rvert \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( \alpha\beta - \beta\alpha)\right\rangle$$

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two possible states of the electron, while $\hat{S^2}$ is the square of the total angular momentum operator

Comment: It looks like your issue is with the [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation). For an operator $A$ and vector $\psi$, $\langle \psi|A|\psi \rangle$ is the inner product between $\psi$ and $A \psi$. In the typical mathematical notation, this expression might be written as $\langle \psi, A \psi \rangle$.

Comment: Also, $\alpha \beta$ likely denotes the tensor product $\alpha \otimes \beta$.

Comment: So you have two electrons, in the singlet state of total angular momentum $j= 0$ which can be writen as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow,\downarrow\rangle - |\downarrow,\uparrow\rangle)$, Isuppose, but it would be better if you provide more details

Comment: @Physor yes, I mean just that!

Comment: Are you absolutely  **sure** you don't really mean $\hat S ^2$ instead?

Comment: in particular, what I wrote should be equal to 0. I would like to understand why, but this is perhaps offtopic

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, is ${\hat{S}}^2$

Answer (score 1):

From your comment you appear to be considering the Casimir operator $ \hat{S} ^2$ instead, and *not* $\hat {S^y}$. In that case, you just do what your textbook teaches you. I'll skip the caret, since the *S*s are always operators, and remind you of the coproduct,
$$
S_i |\alpha\beta \rangle = S_i (|\alpha\rangle \otimes |\beta \rangle)\\
= ( S_i |\alpha\rangle ) \otimes |\beta \rangle + |\alpha\rangle \otimes  (S_i |\beta \rangle)  ~~~\leadsto \\
S_i S_i |\alpha\beta \rangle = ( S_i S_i |\alpha\rangle ) \otimes |\beta \rangle +2 (S_i |\alpha\rangle) \otimes  (S_i |\beta \rangle)  + |\alpha\rangle \otimes  (S_i S_i |\beta \rangle) ,
$$
where the summation convention on all three indices *i* is implied.

You may take it from there and  read off the four terms of your expression,
$\left\langle \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( \alpha\beta - \beta\alpha) \bigg\rvert {S}^2 \bigg\rvert \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( \alpha\beta - \beta\alpha)\right\rangle. $

This is how you read it. However, I strongly suspect you are also asking: How do you evaluate it? In general, it is a mess and involves the Clebsch-Gordan series.

However, if $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$ are in the same representation, and notably the doublet, as per your comments, then, oh, the joy!
$$
S^2 |\alpha\rangle = 3/4~|\alpha\rangle, ~~ S^2 |\beta\rangle = 3/4~|\beta\rangle, ~~~ \vec S| ( \alpha\beta - \beta\alpha)\rangle =0,
$$
and therefore
$$
S^2| ( \alpha\beta - \beta\alpha)\rangle = 0,
$$
and you expression vanishes.